# How do I compress multiple videos for the web using a Mac?

Tags: macos, video, compression, quicktime

I'm uploading some videos to Google + and it's taking forever! So I'd like to compress the videos so they don't take so long to upload. I am aware that quicktime has a compression feature to upload videos to the web. I was wondering if it would be possible to compress multiple videos rather than one at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) for this.

> HandBrake is an open-source, GPL-licensed, multiplatform, multithreaded video transcoder, available for MacOS X, Linux and Windows.

[image]